# Custom Array Model Binder

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I need to understand what I am doing wrong here.

I have a .net 4.7.2 project. 
I have a Controller that inherits from the System.Web.Http.ApiController class.

In the controller I have the following endpoint

```
public HttpResponseMessage EchoIdentifierArray([ModelBinder(typeof(CommaDelimitedArrayBinder))] IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, ids); 
}
```

My idea here is simply a test for the id being passed in.

The custom model binder is as follows:

```
public class CommaDelimitedArrayBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I am using postman to test the end point and I can see the url is in the following format:

/api/v3/Echos/EchoIdentifierArray?ids=160742,160892

Then place a break point on the first line in the endpoint but I am never getting the exception that i am expecting from the ModelBinder.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code according to correct name spaces. I got issues with object type, reason is matching return type should be bool. Please test with below code snippet.

```
public class CommaDelimitedArrayBinder : System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.IModelBinder
{
    public CommaDelimitedArrayBinder()
    {

    }

    public bool BindModel(
            System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext,
            System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I recommend you to follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) article and test and convert to your case.

Comment: This is not required as the linked mentions the declaring at the endpoint is one of the three ways of doing it. Also I tried it just in case and it didn't solve the issue. :)